# Is it possible to avoid encoding padding when creating a sequence data encoder in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, autoencoder

I am attempting to make an observation history encoder, where my goal is for a model that takes in as input a variable length sequence of dimension [Time, Batch, Features] (where sequences are padded to fit a fixed Time length) and outputs a variable of dimension [Batch, New_Features]. My concern is that when I’m doing dimensionality reduction with FC layers, they will take the padded data into consideration. Is there any way to avoid this? Or is this  something I don't need to worry about because the padding will naturally become part of the unique encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to mask padding elements when you pool representations.

For example, say you have an input (with padding) of shape `(bs, sl, n)` and  a binary padding mask of shape `(bs, sl)` that has `1` for non-padding items and `0` for padding items. You could do something like this:

```py
x = ... # (bs, sl, n)
padding_mask = ... # (bs, sl)

embeddings = model(x) # output of size (bs, sl, n)

mean_embeddings = ((embeddings * padding_mask.unsqueeze(-1)).sum(1)) / torch.clamp(padding_mask.sum(-1).unsqueeze(-1), min=1e-9)
```

When we compute `mean_embeddings`, we sum up all the non-padding elements in `embeddings`, then divide by the total number of non-padding elements in each sequence. This create a mean-pooled output of size `(bs, n)` without including padding elements in the pooling calculation.